# VBA: Searching a Database and Copying rows to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am a newbie in VBA so please pardon me. I am having trouble with a piece of code to search a database sheet "4c.CustomerP Database" based on the criteria in cell C14 in sheet "1b.SearchClient" and copy those matching entries into sheet "1b.Search Client". However when i try to execute the code, I receive a error:

> Run-time errow '1004':
>   Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

The debug line brings me to purchases.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 10)).Copy

Hope a kind soul can help me out here!

```
Sub findrecord()


Dim custid As String
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
Dim activeWs As Worksheet
Dim purchases As Worksheet

Set targetWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
Set activeWs = targetWorkbook.Sheets("1b.SearchClient")
Set purchases = targetWorkbook.Sheets("4c.CustomerP Database")

activeWs.Range("A26:J200").ClearContents

custid = activeWs.Range("C14").Value

For i = 7 To 10000
If purchases.Cells(i, 1) = custid Then
    purchases.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 10)).Copy
    activeWs.Range("A1000").End(x1Up).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial x1PasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
    End If
Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Try rather `Range(purchases.Cells(i, 1), purchases.Cells(i, 10)).Copy`

Comment: Or alternatively add `purchases.Activate` above the Copy line. Also there's a typo in End(x1Up)

Answer (score 1):

The cells in the range needs to refer to the purchases also:

```
purchases.Range(purchases.Cells(i, 1), purchases.Cells(i, 10)).Copy
```

Or use With:

```
With purchases
    If .Cells(I, 1) = custid Then
        .Range(.Cells(I, 1), .Cells(I, 10)).Copy
        activeWs.Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
    End If
End With
```